# Accessing Data From an Array With a Counter

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an array structure like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [term_id] => 22
            [name] => Aaa Aa
            [slug] => aaa-aa
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 22
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 13
            [count] => 0
            [cat_ID] => 22
            [category_count] => 0
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Aaa Aa
            [category_nicename] => aaa-aa
            [category_parent] => 13
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [term_id] => 11
            [name] => adasdasda
            [slug] => adasdasda
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 11
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => asdsdad
            [parent] => 1
            [count] => 0
            [cat_ID] => 11
            [category_count] => 0
            [category_description] => asdsdad
            [cat_name] => adasdasda
            [category_nicename] => adasdasda
            [category_parent] => 1
        )
)
```

I was wondering how to go about easily looping through the data for output...

For example, I want to display all the names, descriptions and slugs.

I can't figure out how to display them all...

This is what I have, and it kind of works, however it's throwing and invalid argument.

```
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($data); $i++) {
    foreach($data[$i] as $key => $value){
            echo "KEY: ".$key."<br />\n VALUE: ".$value."<br />\n"; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use the `for` loop, `foreach` will suffice. This way you won't have to deal with the out of boundary (index not set) warning.

```
$array = array(); // <- your data here
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    echo 'Name: ', $arr['name'], '<br />',
         'Description: ', $arr['description'], '<br />',
         'Slug: ', $arr['slug'], '<br />';
}
```

Comment: haha wow, I must have been over thinking it. Can't believe it was a simple as that! Thanks man.

Comment: @Michael: Glad I helped. Feel free to accept an answer so this question gets marked as resolved. :)

Answer (score 1):

You get the warning because you are accessing an element of `$data` that does not exists. The boundary check in the `for` condition is one too high, `count` will return 2, but `$data[2]` is not set and can not be used within `foreach` then.

Instead do ([Demo](http://codepad.org/u36JJvK2)):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) { # $i < count, not $i <= count
    foreach($data[$i] as $key => $value){
        echo "KEY: ".$key."<br />\n VALUE: ".$value."<br />\n"; 
    }
}
```

Naturally it's easier to use an outer `foreach` as well:

```
foreach($data as $oneData)
{
    foreach($oneData as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "KEY: $key<br />\n VALUE: $value<br />\n"; 
    }
}
```

This basically does the same and you don't need to care about the counter variable.

The next thing is that you need to decide which of the data in question you would like to display. Instead of displaying all items, you can pick them selectively:

```
$displayKeys = array('name', 'description', 'slug');

foreach($data as $oneData)
{
    foreach($displayKeys as $key)
    {
        $value = $oneData[$key];
        echo "KEY: $key<br />\n VALUE: $value<br />\n"; 
    }
}
```

Then you might want to label the output:

```
$displayKeys = array('name' => 'Name', 'description' => 'Description', 'slug' => 'Slug');

foreach($data as $oneData)
{
    foreach($displayKeys as $key => $label)
    {
        $value = $oneData[$key];
        echo "$label: $value<br />\n"; 
    }
}
```